# Default Return Value for Resolved Promise

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm learning about writing functions that return promises in ES6, for example:

```
function async() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (doStuff()) {
      resolve(value);
    } else {
      reject(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Sometimes, there is no useful value to pass back in `resolve(value)`. In these cases, what should be the default value to return?

Comment: We just usually call it without an argument, and the promise gets resolved to undefined.

Comment: Actually it is *very* rare that there is no value to pass back. If the caller isn't waiting for *something*, why is he waiting and you returning a promise at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like functions that don't have a `return` statement do return `undefined`, you should return a promise for `undefined`. You can either explicitly pass it into `resolve` or simply omit the argument, which will default to `undefined` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `resolve()` and `reject()` without specifying any argument.

Comment: …but you should *never* use `reject` without an argument.